# How to create a collection structure from a transformation function in datalog?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I would like to create a list from many pattern variables so I could compare the lists instead of the individual pattern variables.

I.e. Instead of writing

```
[:find ?attr
 :where
 ;; Many lines of data patterns and predicates
 ;; And now, the comparison point to point
 [(= :v11 :v21)]
 [(= :v12 :v22)]
 ;; ...
 [(= :v1n :v2n)]]
```

Write something like:

```
[:find ?attr
 :where
 ;; Many lines of data patterns and predicates
 ;; Create 2 lists
 ['(v11 v12 ... v1n) v1]
 ['(v21 v22 ... v2n) v2]
 [(= v1 v2)] ;; <-- Only one line for this comparison in this transformation function
```

I'm aware of the fact I should be using the fqdn of the function, so I imagine I should do `(clojure.core/list ...)` instead of `'(...)`. But in all cases I get the error:

When quoting: **Non-whitelist symbol used in query/args: #{quote}. The symbol whitelist is #{= < sum <=**

When using the fqdn function: **Non-whitelist symbol used in query/args: #{clojure.core/list}. The symbol whitelist is #{= < sum <=**

So:

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Can I create a list of pattern variables values and use it as another pattern variable?

Comment: I don't really understand the question... Can you clarify the example desired behavior?

Comment: @AlanThompson in a datalog query, you can write transformation functions: [(function arg1 ... argn) ?bindin]. But I'm unable to write a transformation function that returns a list. I would like to write [(list ?variable_1 ?variable_2) ?list_1] but I can't.

An explanation of the transformation functions: http://www.learndatalogtoday.org/chapter/6